# Build Docker with Visual Studio with ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production

Tags: c#, docker, build, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't know how to set my docker image as production image. I have tried:

Dockerfile

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
```

Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT["dotnet", "Isofy-Api.dll",  "--environment="Production"]
```

launchSettings.json

```
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": false,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
  }
}
```

And still docker is compiled as a Development. How to fix that?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Reservation2/Reservation2.csproj", "Reservation2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Reservation2/Reservation2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Reservation2"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
RUN dotnet build "Reservation2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
RUN dotnet publish "Reservation2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Reservation2.dll"]
```

Comment: I'm confused that you say `compiled as`. The environment is set at runtime - not at compile time. At compile time, you can compile with the `Release` or `Debug` configuration. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @HansKilian 
No, as you say I want to set environment at runtime. Becouse my app give me error:
`The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.`

Comment: The `ENV` should work, providing the line is placed in the Dockerfile somewhere where it'll end up in the final image. I.e. in the 'base' or 'final' part if you have one of the 4-stage Dockerfiles that MS like. If it's in the 'build' or 'publish' part, it won't be included in the final image. If you still have issues, can you add your complete Dockerfile to your post?

Comment: @HansKilian I post my Dockerfile on top. I put ENV everywhere and still its Development

Answer (score 1):

The default error text in Razor apps (which is what I think you're getting) is

```
The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development
    and restarting the app.
```

You might think that that means that your app is running in development mode. It doesn't. It means that you're *not* running in development mode and that's why you're not getting detailed error information. It then gives you instructions on how to run the app in development mode, so you can get the detailed error information.

If you want to change the text above, it's in Pages/Error.cshtml.

Comment: I have app that work perfectly in IIS on localhost. No errors. But when I make doker this error appear. How to prevent that?